# Cannot read JSON nested file

Tags: c#, file

I have to read a JSON file that is stored locally in my machine but it gives me empty data when I try to access a specific item.

Here's my JSON file structure:

```
{
    "food": [{
            "id": "8a7f65c47cdb33f4017d08fff1fe3cee",
            "rules": [

            ],

            "fruit": "Apple",
            "size": "Large",
            "color": "Red"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
//test.json is the name of my file
string fileName = "test.json";
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
Item item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(jsonString);

//here I want to print out the fruit "Apple" but it gives me null;
Console.WriteLine($"Fruit:" + item.fruit);
```

Item class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string fruit;
    public string size;
    public string color;
    public string id;
    public string rules;
}
```

PS: If I noticed that this code will work only if my data structure is without the "food" block, and it think that is the problem here.
Any ideas on how can I fix this?

Comment: We need to see your `Item` class and it helps if you are more specific than "when I try to access a specific item" - what does this mean exactly? `item` is null? or `item` is an object but one property is empty? Or...

Comment: @christopLutjen Oh yea sorry, I forgot to add that too, updated now.

Comment: Your Json file and your class are not compatible. you'll have to edit the class.
edit: forgot to ask, what is the supposed datatype of the content of "rules" sorry for premature enter

Comment: I have just started working with Json reading and writing and stuff so sorry if this sounds like a dumb question but... does this mean that this file is...unreadable ?

Comment: @questioner9928 for what you are trying to do, your class has to match your json file structure, as it stands now it does not. Try google for JSON to C# Class converter, there are websites that help you generate classes that fit, edit your code accordingly, in this case edit the typing for the DeserializeObject to the proper class and you should be good.

Comment: "is unreadable" ... no, it's no problem. Could you please check if the docs already solve your problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0 (note that there are two JSON libs. JSON.Net and the newer System.Text.Json - the docs are for Text.Json but the rules for nested objects are the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item class doesnt match to your json,
here is my suggest for this case:

```
    public class Food
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<object> rules { get; set; }
    public string fruit { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}

public class FoodList
{
    public List<Food> food { get; set; }
}
```

I created a button to make this convert

```
        private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        string fileName = "YOUR_PATH\\test.json";
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        FoodList l = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FoodList>(jsonString);
  
        tbResult.Text = $"Fruit:" + l.food[0].fruit;

    }
```

Added gif:
[image: DeserializeObject]

Comment: I still get a null result :(

Comment: When you add a breakpoint on `FoodList l = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FoodList>(jsonString);` what  it is look like the Text Visualizer?

Comment: https://codverter.com/src/maineditor?query=d064af8a-8eb6-42c8-b27e-a08dd0d46ce8 , btw I use this web a lot for coding. And for your problem it look like your json doesn't deserialize. did you make any change in the json file from your first post?

Comment: Okay I copied it and run it on my pc and it only works for the first part (reading part) but when I try to parse it and serialize it gives me `WindowsFormsApp2.Form1.FoodList.food.get returned null.` this error.

Comment: Can you send me your json on codverter.com ?

Comment: Can I do it by email?

Answer (score 1):

The *item* class does not represent the correct structure for your JSON data.
You have a root object which contains a property that is a list of another object.

To correctly deserialize your JSON data your class should look something like this:

```
public class Food
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<object> rules { get; set; }
    public string fruit { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Food> food { get; set; }
}
```

You can use [this](https://json2csharp.com/) to quickly generate fitting models in C# from JSON data.

Comment: Add mention of needed changes for this to work: `Root item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);` and `Console.WriteLine($"Fruit:" + item.food[0].fruit);`

Answer (score 0):

Your **Item** class does not match the JSON datastructure. You are missing that *food* is a List of Objects in the JSON structure. Your Item class only represents the Object right now. It also misses that rules is a List too.

Try:

```
public class Food
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<object> rules { get; set; }
    public string fruit { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Food> food { get; set; }
}
```

You would also need to change *Item* to *Root* like this:

```
Root item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

Then you should find *fruit* like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Fruit:" + item.food[0].fruit);
```